# Python pandas dataframe: How to count and show the number of missing value in dataframe only?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to ask how to count and show the number of missing value in dataframe only? 
I am using: 
`df.isna().sum()`  but it will show all columns including non-missing value columns. How can I only count and show the columns with missing value with descending order value counts in dataframe?

Thank so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion simpliest is remove `0` values by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and then [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sort_values.html):

```
s = df.isna().sum()
s = s[s != 0].sort_values(ascending=False)
```

Or use [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) for filter only columns with at least one `True` (one `NaN`):

```
df1 = df.isna()
s = df1.loc[:, df1.any()].sum().sort_values(ascending=False)
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('abcdef'),
         'B':[np.nan,5,np.nan,5,5,np.nan],
         'C':[7,8,9,np.nan,2,3],
         'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
         'E':[np.nan,3,6,9,2,np.nan],
         'F':list('aaabbb')
})

s = df.isna().sum()
s = s[s != 0].sort_values(ascending=False)
print (s)
B    3
E    2
C    1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pipe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html) to remove zero values from your totals:

```
>>> df.isnull().sum().sort_values(ascending=False).pipe(lambda s: s[s > 0])
B    3
E    2
C    1
dtype: int64
```